# Git - Hide part of remote url

Tags: git, jazz, ibm-jazz

I am working on a private repo hosted on `IBM-jazz`.

First, when I wanted to clone this repo, I had to type the following command:

```
git clone https://user_name:password@hub.jazz.net/git/repo_owner/repo_name
```

When doing:

```
git remote show origin
```

It shows my credentials...

Is there anyway to prevent this from happening?

Comment: You could leave the password off, but you'd have to type it in every time you fetch, push or pull. The best solution is not to use HTTPS at all, do git over SSH instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the credentials and use the [git credential cache](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache) to cache them in memory and ease the pain of typing them. You can even [store the credentials on disk](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store), but keep in mind that this will store the password in plain-text.

A possible configuration (taken from [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache)) for caching the credentials for 5 minutes would be:

```
git config credential.helper 'cache --timeout=300'
```